# Remove all the characters and special characters except underscores, dashes and numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

Currently having a problem with removing all the alphabetic characters from string except '_', '-' and numbers.My string looks like follows.

```
let str = '/Anna-Charoline_1985-02-14_London/';
```

And i have tried following code to remove the unwanted characters.

```
let formatted = str.replace(/[D&\/\\#,+()$~%.'":*?<>{}]/g, '');
```

It did't work. Can anyone help me with this please? Expected output is `_1985-02-14_`.

Comment: Way easier with a _negated_ character class - `/[^0-9_-]/g`

Comment: What the above said + you forgot to add the a-zA-Z selector to remove the letters. `str.replace(/[a-zA-ZD&\/\\#,+()$~%.'":*?<>{}]/g, '')`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is way easier with a *negated* character class:

```
str.replace(/[^0-9_-]/g, '');
```

Everything that is *not* a digit between 0 and 9, an underscore or a minus, will get replaced by an empty string.

(The first `-` means “range” here, because it is between two other characters, the second one just means “itself”, because it is at the end of the character class. If it was placed somewhere other than the very start or end, it would need to be escaped, `\-`.)